# how to print part of a variable to the screen using substring & determining if input has an '@' symbol in it using indexOf method

Tags: java, indexof

My assignment:
Your program should verify that the email address entered contains an @ symbol. If it does not, your program should notify the user that the email address is invalid. The program should then exit the program after printing a “Goodbye!” message.

TIP: Consider using a branching statement (if/else) to handle continuing the program or exiting the program if email is entered incorrectly.

TIP: Consider using the indexOf() method that belongs to the String class to determine the email address contains an @ symbol.

I'm not sure how to do this; the email address is declared by the user's input, so it's asking you to declare the variable username by using this input but all the characters before the @ sign (juliariccio@gmail.com - wants you to print juliariccio as username).

**Also, trying to figure out how to fix this error that keeps popping up for all of the branching statements:

`````````
        case "1": System.out.println("\nClassification:       Freshman");
             ^
  required: char
  found:    String
My code for the program is below:

````````//import Scanner documentation
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Riccio_Lesson6  {
    public static void main (String [ ] args) {

    //declare variables
    String fname, lname;
    String emailAddress;
    int atSign;

    //create a scanner object
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    //prompt user for first and last name
    System.out.print("Please enter your first and last name: ");

    //read user's first name
    fname = keyboard.next();

    //read user's last name
    lname = keyboard.next();

    //prompt user for their email address
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your email address: ");

    //read user's input
    emailAddress = keyboard.next();

    //prompt user for their major & classification code
    System.out.print("Pleast enter two characters (Character #1: Major Code and Character #2: Classification Code): ");

    //read user's input
    String input = keyboard.next();
    char major = input.charAt(0);
    char classification = input.charAt(1);

    //print banner to screen
    System.out.print("\n*******************************************************************************************************");
    System.out.print("\n             " + fname.toUpperCase() );
    System.out.print(", please review your profile below and learn more about your major.");
    System.out.print("\n*******************************************************************************************************");

    //create username
    atSign = emailAddress.lastIndexOf("@");
    username = emailAddress.substring(atSign);

    //print outputs to screen
    System.out.print("\n\nFirst Name:       " + fname);
    System.out.print("\nLast Name:        " + lname);
    System.out.print("\n\nUsername:       " + username);
    System.out.print("\nEmail Address:    " + emailAddress);

       //use a switch statement to determine the user's classification
    switch (classification){
        case "1": System.out.println("\nClassification:       Freshman");
                    break;
        case "2": System.out.println("\nClassification:       Sophomore");
                   break;
        case "3": System.out.println("\nClassification:       Junior");
                    break;
        case "4": System.out.println("\nClassification:       Senior");
                    break;
        case "5": System.out.println("\nClassification:       Graduate");
                    break;

        default: System.out.println("\nYou've entered an invalid year code!");
   }

    //use a switch statement to determine the user's major
    switch (major){
          case "A": System.out.println("\nMajor:       Accounting");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   Accounting supplies quantitative information essential to management decision-making and control, as well as a wide variety of tax and consulting services and information on management's effective use of an organization's resources. This major helps prepare students for careers in public, industrial, or governmental accounting and also provides an appropriate background for those planning to enter law school or graduate school. Public accounting is carried on by independent practitioners, most of whom are certified public accountants.");
                      break;
          case "B": System.out.println("\nMajor:       Biology");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   Biology examines the fundamental concepts of nature and all aspects of the living environment, from the molecular level to the biosphere. Biology can open doors to many specialized fields, including genetics, biotechnology, environmental biology, and medicine. A Biology major can prepare students for further study in graduate or professional schools, and also trains students for careers in industry, education, or government.");
                      break;
          case "C": System.out.println("\nMajor:       Computer Science");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   Computer Science is primarily concerned with the analysis, design, and applications of computing software and systems. It includes programming languages, data structures, compilers, operating systems, data bases, and artificial intelligence.");
                      break;
          case "E": System.out.println("\nMajor:       Economics");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   Economics' studies how individuals make choices in the face of scarcity. Whether dealing with how households determine what goods they buy, why firms produce certain quantities of goods and services, and what forces shape the aggregate performance of economic institutions. Economics is valuable not only for the topic it treats, but also for its rigorous methods of analysis. Economic majors often attend graduate school, law school or business school. Majors who choose to work immediately upon graduation may find employment in financial institutions, manufacturing corporations, consulting firms, and state and federal agencies.");
                      break;
          case "H": System.out.println("\nMajor:       History");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   History examines the human experience from its origins to the present. The history of countries such as Europe, Canada, America, China, Japan, India, Africa, or Latin America may be studied. Focus may be placed on public events of political, diplomatic, and constitutional history, or on the examination the social, cultural, or economic history of subjects such as villages, cities, witchcraft, sex, literacy, and work. History majors may go on to graduate school, law school or business school. Some may go into the work force, finding jobs with multinational corporations, governmental agencies, or small businesses.");
                      break;
          case "I": System.out.println("\nMajor:       Information Sciences and Technology");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   This major is structured to provide students with the theoretical frameworks and skill sets necessary to compete and be productive in the information technology -intensive global context that defines the new Information Age. Specifically, the degree will be focused on a program that will build an understanding of core information technologies and related areas of study; will prepare students for the practical application of various information sciences and related technologies; and engage students in sharpening their abilities to think critically and to work in teams.");
                      break;
          case "J": System.out.println("\nMajor:       Journalism");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   Careers include newspaper reporting and editing, magazine writing, broadcast news, corporate public relations, and advertising account services. This major is based on knowledge of the social and professional responsibilities of communicators, and basic competence in journalistic skills.");
                      break;
          case "M": System.out.println("\nMajor:       Mathematics");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   Mathematics today is a vibrant and dynamic field, manifesting itself in such familiar things as CAT scans, compact discs, and satellite communication. Accordingly, the mathematics program is broad and varied, with studies in calculus, finite, actuarial sciences and algebra. After graduating, majors successfully pursue a variety of careers, working in industry, insurance (as actuaries), government, finance, and other fields. Many graduates may attend professional schools in law, medicine, or business. Others may go directly into teaching; and still others may go on to graduate programs in mathematics, applied mathematics, engineering, economics, and computer science.");
                      break;
          case "P": System.out.println("\nMajor:       Physics");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   Physics studies the fundamental properties and interactions of all forms of matter. Experimental and theoretical investigations are combined to formulate mathematical relationships that describe and predict the behavior of nature. The physics undergraduate program can prepare students for employment in an industrial or governmental laboratory. The program can also prepare students for further study at graduate or professional schools in physics, engineering, biophysics, medicine, education, law, or business.");
                      break;
          case "T": System.out.println("\nMajor:       Telecommunications");
                    System.out.println("\nMajor Description:   The primary goal of this major is to prepare students for administrative careers in the electronic media. Its professional emphasis is on management and public policy in telecommunications. Telecommunications may provide course work for students interested in television production, from the perspective of production management and administration. The major also serves students seeking greater understanding of the social role and social control of the broadcasting and cable industries. Telecommunications is especially designed for students considering careers in local cable systems operation, local radio and television station administration, television network and cable MSO operations, corporate video, local and federal public policy positions, and emerging media industries.");
                      break;

       default: System.out.println("\nYou've entered an invalid major code!");
    }

    }//end of main
}//end of CLASS
`````````

Comment: `classification` is type `char`, and the case statement uses strings.  The two aren't directly compatible.  Change the case statements to chars (use single quotes, `case '1':`) or change the type of `classification` String (you'll need to actually make a string from a `char` in that case).

Comment: `I'm not sure how to do this; ... it's asking you to declare the variable username by using this input but all the characters before the @ sign` To declare a new variable that is only part of a string, use `substring` on the larger string (the email in this case).

Comment: This is pretty remedial stuff.  If you're not understanding this, you should talk to your instructor.  They need to know if they're not teaching the material properly.  `substr()` should have been covered in class already.  You can also ask your TA, lab assistant or fellow students to help you out.  The latter will also tell you if they are also confused, which might indicate whether the instructor is teaching properly, or there's things that only you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a switch statement (and get rid of your error), you must use a char value, not a String type. For example, instead of:

```
    switch(major){
        case "A": //case 1
        case "B": //case 2
        case "C": //etc.
```

use:

```
switch(major){
    case 'A': //case 1
    case 'B': //case 2
    case 'C': //etc.
```

To check for the @ symbol with indexOf(), you want it to look more like this:

```
atsign = emailAddress.indexOf('@');
if(atsign >= 0){
    username = emailAddress.substring(0, atsign);
}
```

Basically, indexOf(char c) will return the first index that the specified char c is found, or it will return -1 if that char is not in the String. substring(int start, int end) will return the String in indeces [start, end). Ex.

```
String str = "milkandcookies";
String sub = str.substring(0, 4);
//now printing sub will print "milk"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String emailAddress = keyboard.next();
    String userName = emailAddress.substring(0, emailAddress.indexOf('@'));
    System.out.println(userName);
```

For solving switch case error, replace double quotes of case values with single quotes like

```
    case 'A'
```